# Was there ever any iPod I could manage like Mass Storage device (without iTunes)?

Tags: itunes, ipod-touch, ipod, ipod-nano

I want an iPod for my car because it looks cool, but I can't/don't want to use iTunes/alternatives to manage it. Was there any (old) iPod ever, which I can use without iTunes?

Comment: What computer OS will manage the device?

Comment: Linux mostly, but the point of my question is that I don't want to be bound to an OS or specific software.

Comment: Don't all iPods let you mount it as a mass storage device? Even iPhones have programs to expose a filesystem. I guess I'm not understanding what you want to change. no iTunes on linux and tons of people store files and music and photos on their iOS and older iPod devices.